# How to populate table by commands in the Dockerfile

Tags: postgresql, docker

I build (without errors) `mypostgres` image. There are commands related to `postgresql`:

```
RUN    /etc/init.d/postgresql start &&\
    psql --command "CREATE USER cobrain WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'cobrain';" &&\
    createdb -O cobrain datasets &&\
    psql --command "CREATE TABLE datasets (id varchar PRIMARY KEY, creation_timestamp bigint, type varchar, owner varchar, datafiles varchar[]);" &&\
    psql --command  "INSERT INTO datasets (id, creation_timestamp, type, owner, datafiles) VALUES ('111', 1111345, 'MEDICAL', 'Yandex', ARRAY['blood.data'])"
```

I run container by:

```
docker run -p 32779:5432 mypostgres:latest
```

Then in another terminal I tried to access postgres service:

```
psql -h localhost -p 32779 -U cobrain datasets
datasets=# select * from datasets;
ERROR:  relation "datasets" does not exist
```

or

```
datasets=# \dt;
No relations found.
```

These messages are strange for me, because I created and inserted value into table. How to overcome them and do `select` statement?

Comment: Probably the table is in a different schema. The user that created the table was not `cobrain`.  Should create the table when connected as `cobrain` if that was the intention.

Comment: Have you run the command inside the docker or are you trying to connect to database on host?

Comment: @JakubKania I tried to connect from host, not inside container.

Comment: @Glenn How to run psql command as another user`?

Comment: Just run your create table and insert statements from the client terminal (which you are connecting `-U corbain`). Your docker container just needed to create the user and start the instance and not create/insert.

Comment: @Glenn How can I do it inside `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Use the command line parameter on the psql commands to that are creating the table and inserting a record: `psql --command "CREATE TABLE ..." -U corbain`.

Comment: to avoid fighting ` &&\` you could `RUN    /etc/init.d/postgresql start && psql -f file.sql` putting all sql inside file?..